# Dashboard url doesn't work even though port is open

Tags: kubernetes, port, dashboard

I want to access the Kubernetes dashboard on my MacBook (using the URL on my web browser), however even though port 36635 is open on my remote Google Linux VM I can't seem to access it. What am I doing wrong? How can I make this URL specify the public IP of the VM for being able to access the dashboard from the internet?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is locahost accesible only from the very container(localhost).

0.0.0.0 is localhost accesible from anywhere in the network.

You need to run the dashboard on 0.0.0.0 so it can be access from anywhere it in the network. To clarify this, your kubernetes host (your PC) is different localhost(127.0.0.1) than your kubernetes container.

This rule is applicable across everything. If you want to access anything running in the network, that thing needs to be running as 0.0.0.0:port. Whenever you work with docker/kubernetes(minikube), always keep in mind that they are not your localhost and they operate as 'servers' in your network

Comment: Ok this makes sense but how can I run it on 0.0.0.0? How can I make it point to the public IP address of the Google VM?

Comment: I am not expert on kubernetes, but this is generally done with Ingress controller + Service, which is basically nginx. If you want to access privately, just for testing, use port forwarding

Comment: thanks! i ended up using ssh local forwarding